# Display MySQL as part of a Page

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database created in MySQL and would like to display SQL quires on a page on my WordPress site. How do I set this up? Is there a plugin I should use? I would like to write my own SQL queries, I just need to know how to go about this.

Also I'd just like to make sure that the page can be different for each user, not just the same query for each user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Custom queries will be better choice for you. I hope this will help you to start 
[WordPress custom queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries)

Comment: Link only answers are actively discouraged here, provide necessary details related to the question.